# How to boot gentoo with systemd, UEFI, lvm2 rootfs with systemd EFI boot?

Tags: boot, systemd, lvm, gentoo, uefi

I've installed Arch Linux with that setup. And now, I want to have dual
boot with gentoo. But, when booting gentoo, the root UUID (on LVM) not
detected. My partition scheme is like this: (`lsblk -f`)

```
sda                                                                    
├─sda1         vfat        E3B9-CCB0                               /boot
└─sda2         LVM2_member GwYKZG-fjl2-UV2L-KX57-1O8J-rBdp-fpdheC 
  ├─lvm-arch   ext4        67ce60f0-1a30-4da3-bb14-8dbfa0e4ea1d    /
  └─lvm-gentoo ext4        4db48ce0-3163-4a4d-ab8a-1961935cb680
```

I can boot Arch linux with `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` config file:

```
title           Arch Linux (LVM)
linux           /vmlinuz-arch
initrd          /initramfs-arch.img
options         root=UUID=67ce60f0-1a30-4da3-bb14-8dbfa0e4ea1d rw
```

After finished gentoo installation, I create `/boot/loader/entries/gentoo.conf` file:

```
title           Gentoo (LVM)
linux           /vmlinuz-gentoo
initrd          /initramfs-gentoo.img
options         root=UUID=4db48ce0-3163-4a4d-ab8a-1961935cb680 rw
```

I use `/boot/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi` to boot. The gentoo option did
show up on boot menu, but when I select it no response at all. Just blank. I
tried to boot on virtualbox directly using my hard drive, then boot works only
until finding `rootfs`. Somehow, `/dev/mapper/lvm-gentoo` UUID can not be
found. Only `/dev/sda2` UUID is detected.

My guess, something wrong with the kernel or initramfs. But, I did compile
the kernel with Device mapper support. And I didn't for get to do:

```
genkernel --lvm --install initramfs
```

What did I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As you need to use not only Logical Volume Manager (LVM) but Universal Unique Identifier (UUID), you should add another option to genkernel command which is `--disklabel` which will result in something like this

```
genkernel --lvm --disklabel --install initramfs
```

using `--disklabel` option will ensure that `blkid` and other command are included in initramfs and are available during the boot phase.

Other advice is try another option to be sure that all driver are available too. Maybe you have build them as modules and not in kernel. `--all-ramdisk-modules` will include all kernel modules in initramfs image. This is not mandatory but you could try it just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The systemd-boot loader-file should look something like this if root is located on an logical volume:

```
title      Debian10
linux      /vmlinuz-4.19.0-4-amd64
initrd     /initrd.img-4.19.0-4-amd64
options    root=/dev/mapper/VG01-LV01 rw
```

To get the LV path use:
`lsblk --path --output name,kname,fstype,mountpoint,model`
(the `name` column)